# Mock Repository vs. Real Repository w/Mocked Data

Tags: unit-testing, repository, domain-driven-design

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

I am implmenting my repositories and then testing them with mocked data. All is well.

Now I want to test my domain objects so I point them at mock repositories.

But I'm finding that I have to re-implement logic from the 'real' repositories into the mocks, or, create 'helper classes' that encapsulate the logic and interact with the repositories (real or mock), and then I have to test *those* too.

So what am I missing - why implement and test mock repositories when I could use the real ones with mocked data?

EDIT: To clarify, by 'mocked data' I do not hit the actual database. I have a 'DB mock layer' I can insert under the real repositories that returns known-data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your mixing your abstractions. maybe some of the helpers and logic that your talking about should  be in your domain objects. Your repositories should be implementing a CRUD interface. So your domain logic should be using 8 actions from the repository. Good retrieve and Bad retrieve (exception thrown) are only two of the eight. One test, is how is the Bad retrieve handled in the domain object. The rest of the tests should be testing a Good retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is meant to minimize the tested element -> test data route, in order to reduce search time if a bug occurs - the bug is either in the routine you test or the test unit and nothing else (well, maybe the OS or the compiler... but these are very rare).

Now imagine you made a database accessor module. The module seems to work ok. Then you make a config reader that reads from the database. Instead of a mock database accessor module unit test, you use your real database module on top of mock config data in the database test unit. It still seems to work OK. Now you add a GUI layer that uses the config object returned by the config reader unit. Instead of mocking the "boiled" config data you use the real module which apparently works.
And now your GUI stops working for a certain value. Where is the error? In the GUI, in the config reader, in the database accessor or in the values in the mock database?

In other words, you're not just testing the code you're writing, you're testing the real repository system as well, and if a bug is found you have an additional layer to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

> why implement and test mock
>   repositories when I could use the real
>   ones with mocked data?

I guess it really comes down to how much code coverage you think you need to have.  If you feel the repository is sound and you can use it for testing, go for it.  Perhaps the repository unit tests can be run prior to the mock database unit tests, so that you can use the real repositories for testing and feel confident that the testing is still valid.

Comment: Good point, although I failed to describe my mock-data. Edited original question with detail.

Comment: What's wrong with a DB Mock layer? Sounds like a perfectly sensible approach to me.